# Sequelize - how to select COUNT(*) and do GROUP BY?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to achieve the following using Sequelize:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY status;
```

So far i have this:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
   myTable()
        .findAll({
            attributes: ['status', Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('status'))],
            group: 'status'
        })
```

But it's not working.
I'm getting the different `status`es in my table, but not their counts:

```
[
    {
        "status": "stat1"
    },
    {
        "status": "stat2"
    },
    {
        "status": "stat3"
    }
]
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

`[Sequelize.literal('COUNT(*)'), 'count']`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
User.groupCount = async (receiverId, query = true) => {
  const data = await sequelize.query(
      `SELECT CAST(count(*) as integer) as total
        FROM (SELECT "statusId"
            FROM "userG"roup
            where TRUE
            GROUP BY "statusId") as "tmp";
      `,
      { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
  );

  return _.get(data, '[0].total', 0);
};
```